# What formula would I use to calculate monthly cost?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to make a Google Sheets that will list my total expenditures in the form of recurring fees/subscriptions. I've successfully enabled the basic 'SUM=(C2:C24)', but I would like to add a caveat; periods of time. To clarify, some of my expenditures are every three months and some are every month. I would like to take this into account. An example:

I pay Last.fm $9 every 3 months for their premium service. While I could simply change the price column to $3/month, I would like to be able to account for this using the formula. I am not familiar with formulas in Excel or Google Sheets beyond being able to read them.

Comment: If you want to do this in Google Docs, this question should be on Webapps.  If you want to do this in Excel, then you should say so explicitly rather than just alluding to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column A can be the recurring cost. Column B can be the number of months in the recurrence. Column C can divide Column A by Column B to get the monthly cost. Then you can sum column C. For your last.fm example:

> `A2 = "9.00"`
>   `B2 = "3"`
>   `C2 = "=A2/B2"`

The your total monthly cost would be the sum of Column C.